# A route between networks stopped working

Tags: vpn, hyper-v

*Small introduction: I recently inherited network administrator role in a small firm, because my colleague died unexpectedly. I'm a programmer and have some very shallow knowledge about how networks are working, so please forgive me in advance for too much/little/nonsensical information in this question.*

On a windows server in our network are 2 Hyper-V machines running, let's call them Router-A and Router-B. Both have Windows 10 Enterprise as OS and using `Palo Alto GlobalProtect` (although different versions) to establish VPN connection into clients' networks.

Client A asked me to restart the VPN connection, due to some weirdness of the GlobalProtect version I decided to restart the whole Virtual PC.

After that, when Router-A was up again I checked the VPN from inside of Router-A -- it was working. Client was happy.

Unfortunately, trying to ping a valid IP address in the A network from host machine didn't work. A ping into B network did still work.

And now (after some hours of searching and experimenting) I'm asking for help.

Network info:

- our subnetwork: 147.44.7.0/24
- client A: router: 147.44.7.6; IP: 192.168.101.0/24
- client B: router: 147.44.7.7; IP: 172.20.5.0/24

On host machine (sry, OS language is German):

```
C:\Users\myuser>route print -4
===========================================================================
Schnittstellenliste
 46...........................RAS (Dial In) Interface
 27...2c 76 8a 4e f2 79 ......Hyper-V-Adapter - virtuelles Ethernet #2
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 18...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft-ISATAP-Adapter #2
 22...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft-ISATAP-Adapter #4
 24...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
===========================================================================

IPv4-Routentabelle
===========================================================================
Aktive Routen:
     Netzwerkziel    Netzwerkmaske          Gateway    Schnittstelle Metrik
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       147.44.7.9       147.44.7.1    261
         10.8.0.0      255.255.0.0      147.44.7.65       147.44.7.1      6
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
       147.44.7.0    255.255.255.0   Auf Verbindung        147.44.7.1    261
       147.44.7.1  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung        147.44.7.1    261
      147.44.7.28  255.255.255.255      147.44.7.28      147.44.7.90     24
      147.44.7.34  255.255.255.255      147.44.7.34      147.44.7.90     24
      147.44.7.90  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung       147.44.7.90    279
     147.44.7.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung        147.44.7.1    261
       172.20.5.0    255.255.255.0       147.44.7.7       147.44.7.1      6
    192.168.101.0    255.255.255.0       147.44.7.6       147.44.7.1      6
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung        147.44.7.1    261
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung       147.44.7.90    279
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung        147.44.7.1    261
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung       147.44.7.90    279
===========================================================================
Ständige Routen:
  Netzwerkadresse          Netzmaske  Gatewayadresse  Metrik
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       147.44.7.9  Standard
       172.20.5.0    255.255.255.0       147.44.7.7       1
         10.8.0.0      255.255.0.0      147.44.7.65       1
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       147.44.7.9     256
    192.168.101.0    255.255.255.0       147.44.7.6       1
===========================================================================

C:\Users\myuser>tracert 172.20.5.132

Routenverfolgung zu 172.20.5.132 über maximal 30 Hops

  1    <1 ms     *       <1 ms  wmsrv08-11.mycompany.de [147.44.7.7]
  2     *        *        *     Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
  3    24 ms    30 ms    21 ms  192.168.82.1
  4    31 ms    32 ms    23 ms  172.20.5.132

Ablaufverfolgung beendet.

C:\Users\myuser>tracert 192.168.101.137

Routenverfolgung zu 192.168.101.137 über maximal 30 Hops

  1     *        *        *     Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
  2     *        *        *     Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
  3     *        *        *     Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
  4     *        *        *     Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
  5     *        *        *     Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
  6     *        *        *     Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
  7     *        *        *     Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
  8     *        *        *     Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
  9     *        *        *     Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
 10     *        *        *     Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
 11     *        *        *     Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
 12     *        *        *     Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
 13     *        *        *     Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
 14     *        *        *     Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
 15     *        *        *     Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
 16     *        *        *     Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
 17     *        *        *     Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
 18     *     ^C
C:\Users\myuser>
```

`ping` to neither of routers works.

From inside Router-A:

```
C:\Users\VPN>tracert 192.168.101.137

Routenverfolgung zu redacted_clientA_name.intern [192.168.101.137] über maximal 30 Hops: 

1    26 ms     28 ms     24 ms     192.168.171.129
2    24 ms     47 ms     23 ms     192.168.235.2
3    25 ms     24 ms     24 ms     redacted_clientA_name.intern [192.168.101.137] 

Üblaufverfolgung beendet.

C:\Users\VPN>ipconfig /all

Windows-IP-Konfiguration

Hostname . . . . . . . . . . . . : wmsrv08-10
Primäres DNS-Suffix . . . . . . . : mycompany.de
Knotentyp . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
IP-Routing aktiviert . . . . . . : Nein
WINS-Proxy aktiviert . . . . . . : Nein
DNS-Suffixsuchliste . . . . . . . : mycompany.de

Ethernet-Adapter Ethernet 8:

Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:
Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : PANGP Virtual Ethernet Adapter #7
Physische Adresse . . . . . . . . : 02-50-41-00-00-01
DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Nein
Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja
IPv4-Adresse . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.171.153(Bevorzugt)
Subnetzmaske . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0
DHCPv6-IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 184700993
DHCPv6-Client-DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1F-27-7E-FF-00-15-5D-07-01-11
DNS-Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.101.163
192.168.101.164
NetBIOS über TCP/IP . . . . . . . : Aktiviert

Ethernet-Adapter Ethernet:

Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix: 
Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter
Physische Adresse . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-07-01-11
DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Nein
Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja
Verbindungslokale IPv6-Adresse . : fe80::519e:598f:9505:2c8a%16(Bevorzugt)
IPv4-Adresse . . . . . . . . . . : 147.44.7.6(Bevorzugt)
Subnetzmaske . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . : 147.44.7.9
DHCPv6-IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 50337117
DHCPv6-Client-DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1F-27-7E-FF-00-15-5D-07-01-11
DNS-Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 147.44.7.1
147.44.7.22
NetBIOS über TCP/IP . . . . . . . : Aktiviert
```

From inside Router-B:

```
C:\Users\VPN>tracert 172.20.5.132

Routenverfolgung zu redacted_clientB_name.de [172.20.5.132] über maximal 30 Hops: 

1    21 ms     35 ms     20 ms     192.168.82.1
2    24 ms     32 ms     21 ms     redacted_clientB_name.de [172.20.5.132] 

Üblaufverfolgung beendet.

C:\Users\VPN>ipconfig -all

Windows-IP-Konfiguration

Hostname . . . . . . . . . . . . : wmsrv08-11
Primäres DNS-Suffix . . . . . . . : wmdom03.mycompany.de
Knotentyp . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
IP-Routing aktiviert . . . . . . : Nein
WINS-Proxy aktiviert . . . . . . : Nein
DNS-Suffixsuchliste . . . . . . . : redacted_clientB_name1.de
redacted_clientB_name2.com
redacted_clientB_name3.com
wmdom03.mycompany.de

Ethernet-Adapter Ethernet 6:

Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:
Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : PANGP Virtual Ethernet Adapter #5
Physische Adresse . . . . . . . . : 02-50-41-00-00-01
DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Nein
Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja
Verbindungslokale IPv6-Adresse . : fe80::6813:ec02:5ae6:9926%8(Bevorzugt)
IPv4-Adresse . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.82.104(Bevorzugt)
Subnetzmaske . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . :
DHCPv6-IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 235032641
DHCPv6-Client-DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-20-4E-EA-29-00-15-5D-07-01-12
DNS-Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 144.4.190.35
144.4.190.34
NetBIOS über TCP/IP . . . . . . . : Aktiviert

Ethernet-Adapter Ethernet:

Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix: wmdom03.mycompany.de
Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter
Physische Adresse . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-07-01-12
DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Nein
Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja
Verbindungslokale IPv6-Adresse . : fe80::88d1:57f4:209c:943a%10(Bevorzugt)
IPv4-Adresse . . . . . . . . . . : 147.44.7.7(Bevorzugt)
Subnetzmaske . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . : 147.44.7.9
DHCPv6-IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 50337117
DHCPv6-Client-DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-20-4E-EA-29-00-15-5D-07-01-12
DNS-Server . . . . . . . . . . . : fd3f:a1ac:46f3:1::1
fd3f:a1ac:46f3:1::3
147.44.7.1
147.44.7.22
NetBIOS über TCP/IP . . . . . . . : Aktiviert
Suchliste für verbindungsspezifische DNS-Suffixe:
wmdom03.mycompany.de
```

ipconfig on host:

```
C:\Windows\system32>ipconfig /all

Windows-IP-Konfiguration

Hostname . . . . . . . . . . . . : wmsrv08
Primäres DNS-Suffix . . . . . . . : wmdom03.mycompany.de
Knotentyp . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
IP-Routing aktiviert . . . . . . : Ja
WINS-Proxy aktiviert . . . . . . : Nein
DNS-Suffixsuchliste . . . . . . . : wmdom03.mycompany.de

PPP-Adapter RAS (Dial In) Interface:

Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:
Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : RAS (Dial In) Interface
Physische Adresse . . . . . . . . :
DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Nein
Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja
IPv4-Adresse . . . . . . . . . . : 147.44.7.90(Bevorzugt)
Subnetzmaske . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . :
NetBIOS über TCP/IP . . . . . . . : Aktiviert

Ethernet-Adapter vEthernet (Intranet):

Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:
Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V-Adapter - virtuelles Ethernet #2
Physische Adresse . . . . . . . . : 2C-76-8A-4E-F2-79
DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Nein
Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja
IPv6-Adresse. . . . . . . . . . . : fd3f:a1ac:46f3:1::1(Bevorzugt)
Verbindungslokale IPv6-Adresse . : fe80::58c9:5b1d:1ee8:dc48%27(Bevorzugt)
IPv4-Adresse . . . . . . . . . . : 147.44.7.1(Bevorzugt)
Subnetzmaske . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . : 147.44.7.9
DHCPv6-IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 657225354
DHCPv6-Client-DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-18-06-CD-D6-2C-76-8A-4E-F2-78

DNS-Server . . . . . . . . . . . : ::1
fd3f:a1ac:46f3:1::3
127.0.0.1
147.44.7.22
NetBIOS über TCP/IP . . . . . . . : Deaktiviert

Tunneladapter isatap.{6E06F030-7526-11D2-BAF4-00600815A4BD}:

Medienstatus. . . . . . . . . . . : Medium getrennt
Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:
Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft-ISATAP-Adapter #2
Physische Adresse . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Nein
Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja

Tunneladapter isatap.{EABE234A-7FED-4815-B40F-E87C6BDD4EE3}:

Medienstatus. . . . . . . . . . . : Medium getrennt
Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:
Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft-ISATAP-Adapter #4
Physische Adresse . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Nein
Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja

Tunneladapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

Medienstatus. . . . . . . . . . . : Medium getrennt
Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:
Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
Physische Adresse . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Nein
Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja
```

Can someone help me? Is this even the right place for this kind of questions (sry if not)?

Till now the only differences I see between the 2 routers is following.

1. The DNS-Searchlist in router-B has 4 entries, last one "wmdom03.mycompany.de", and this suffix is also seen as "Connectionspecific DNS-Suffix" in `ipconfig /all`; in router-A, the search list only has a single entry -- "wmdom03.mycompany.de", and "Connectionspecific DNS-Suffix" stays empty unless I set the "DNS-Suffix for this connection" explicitly.
2. Both router-A and -B have IPv6 enabled and set to discover DNS-Serveraddress automatically, but only router-B got them.

**UPDATE1**: add `ipconfig /all` for the 3 relevant systems.
**UPDATE2**: add discovered differences between router

Comment: A strange name for a Windows 10 Enterprise system, "Router-A".  Router-A could be running a firewall.

Comment: Any idea what 192.168.82.1 would be?

Comment: "Router-A" is just a name I chose for -- I hoped -- brevity. It's name from our dns-server is actually "wmsrv08-10", and since it's a hyper-v virtual machine I can look into it -- "System Information" of Windows states OS name as "Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise".  The `192.168.82.1` must be some router in client B's network, I doubt it's relevant, because in case A tracert doesn't even hop to "wmsrv08-10" aka "router A".

Comment: Apart from beiing weird, what is the role of the "Palo Alto GlobalProtect VPN"?  I see it can act as firewall.  Can you compare the configurations of GlobalProtect between A en B?

Comment: it's the piece of software the provides the actual VPN connection to the client (I have no idea why couldn't we just use the Windows' build-in VPN, but for some reason for some clients we do while others -- like this one -- requires a special 3rd-party software)

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I can compare the configs as in I have admin access to them, but I have no idea what to look for. They look similar enough.

Comment: Select move to chat if you prefer.  Follow this guide on both systems, https://knowledgebase.paloaltonetworks.com/KCSArticleDetail?id=kA10g000000ClFbCAK,   look for differences.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107918/discussion-between-tymur-gubayev-and-gerard-h-pille).